# If $x + y = xy$ for some $y$, then $ x\ne 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have prove this $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} [ \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (x + y = xy) \iff x \neq 1]$$

which I divided in the usual 2 cases:

**Case 1:**

> $x + y = x*y \rightarrow x \neq 1$
>
> We want to prove $ x \neq 1$
>
> We have $x + y = x*y$
>
> Which is equivalent $x = y(x - 1)$
>
> Now by contradiction, suppose $x = 1$
>
> If we replace 1 in the right side of the expression, 
>       we obtain $x = 0$, which is a contradiction,     so $x \neq 1$

But for the second case I am having some difficulties:

Case 2:

> $x \neq 1 \rightarrow x + y = x*y$
>
> $x + y \neq x*y \rightarrow x = 1$
>
> Now we want to prove $x = 1$
>
> By contradiction, we have that $x \neq 1$

But I do not know how to continue...

Comment: For first case is simpler and more elegant solution. Assume $x=1$, then you recive $1 +y = 1\cdot y \Leftrightarrow 1 = 0$. However, it '$\to$' your implication? Then I suggest use $\Rightarrow$ `\Rightarrow`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply rewrite $xy=x+y$ as $(x-1)(y-1)=1$ and see.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \Bbb{R}\backslash\{1\}$ and let $y = \frac{x}{x-1}$. Then $$x+y = x+\frac{x}{x-1} \\ = \frac{x(x-1)}{(x-1)} + \frac{x}{x-1} \\ = \frac{x^2-x+x}{x-1} \\ = \frac{x^2}{x-1} \\ = x\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right) \\ = xy$$

Comment: @Broly I thought case two was $x\neq 1 \implies $ there exists a $y$ such that $x+y = xy$

Comment: @Broly you just described the entire collective body of mathematics. You prove new things by using things that were previously proven...

Comment: @Broly you are doing an equivalence proof right? You have already shown that $x+y = xy \implies x \neq 1$, so you next show that $x \neq 1 \implies x+y = xy$. This is what I did in my proof above. Then you combine the two results to get $x+y=xy \iff x \neq 1$